# QQ.com does not accept email from our domain

Tags: email

We are running a mailing list by OpenEMM for our customers. However, email addresses in the `@qq.com` are not delivered.

It seems to us `qq.com` does not accept any email from our domain.

How can this be fixed?

p.s. SPF record is already set up for our domain.

Typical maillog entries:

```
Sep  9 00:06:02 MAILER sendmail[982]: 0000DB00000001922: to=<MASKED@qq.com>, delay=00:03:11, xdelay=00:00:09, mailer=esmtp, pri=0, relay=mx3.qq.com. [103.7.29.244], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Sep  9 00:14:51 MAILER sendmail[1067]: 0000DB00000001B8A: to=<MASKED@qq.com>, delay=00:12:00, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=0, relay=mx3.qq.com. [103.7.29.244], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

Comment: Why don't you ask them that?

Comment: qq.com is bigger than Yahoo and Google in China. Any experience of sending email to them is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The log entries you posted indicate the most generic possible failure, `5.0.0 Service unavailable`. This says absolutely nothing about why the message was rejected. It could be because the mail server isn't functioning correctly, or because it just doesn't want to talk to you, or any number of reasons. The only real way to find out what's going on is to contact the postmaster at the remote domain.